# Select closest time base on current time

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list of time of the whole day and wanted the time should be selected base on how much it's close to current time.

```js
now = 11:18; 
$(function(){
 
})
```

```css
.selected{
  font-weight:bold;
}
```

```html
<li class="selected">11:00</li>
<li>11:30</li>
<li>12:00</li>
<li>12:30</li>
<li>1:00</li>
<li>1:30</li>
<li>2:30</li>
<li>3:00</li>
```

^ Selected time on the list should be now switch to 11:30 because it's no longer close to 11:00.

I'm stuck somewhere, I know I should get the the time different and divide by 2, but have no idea how to continue.

Comment: please share a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: @gurvinder372 https://jsfiddle.net/ptfa9a04/2/

Comment: are list items always in sorted order? does 1:00 mean 1300 or 1PM?

Comment: @gurvinder372 sorted, I didn't list all of them, it's in 24 hr format

Comment: why `now = 11:16; //selected should be 1:30` ?? should not it be `11:30`??

Comment: @ozil it should be `11:30`,why `1:30`? typo maybe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `.filter(0)` , `String.prototype.replace()` , using `.data()` to store 24 hour representation of `li` text, casting `data-*` attribute and `now` to `Number` , `.eq(0)` to select first match , `.siblings()`

```js
var now = "1116";
$(function() {
  $("li").filter(function() {
    return +$(this).data().t > +(now) && +$(".selected").data().t
  }).eq(0).addClass("selected").siblings().removeClass("selected")
})
```

```css
.selected {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<li class="selected" data-t="1100">11:00</li>
<li data-t="1130">11:30</li>
<li data-t="1200">12:00</li>
<li data-t="1230">12:30</li>
<li data-t="1300">1:00</li>
<li data-t="1330">1:30</li>
<li data-t="1430">2:30</li>
<li data-t="1530">3:00</li>
```

jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/ptfa9a04/9/

Comment: what if by default I don't want li to be selected?

Comment: @Jennifer _"what if by default I don't want li to be selected?"_ Could remove `&& +$(".selected").data().t` from `.filter()` return statement.

Answer (score 2):

Heres another way to do it

```js
var now = "12:18";

$(function() {
    var els    = $('ul li'),
 times  = els.map(function() { return $(this).text() }).get(),
     diff   = Infinity, i = 0
    
    times.forEach(function(time, index) {
     var a1 = now.split(':');
     var d1 = new Date(2015, 1, 1, a1[0], a1[1]);
        var a2 = time.split(':');
        var d2 = new Date(2015, 1, 1, a2[0], a2[1]);
        var d  = Math.abs(d1-d2);
        
        if ( d < diff ) {
         diff = d; i = index;
        }
    });
    
    els.eq(i).addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected')
});
```

```css
.selected {
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul>
    <li>11:00</li>
    <li>11:30</li>
    <li>12:00</li>
    <li>12:30</li>
    <li>1:00</li>
    <li>1:30</li>
    <li>2:30</li>
    <li>3:00</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: does the date matter here `var d1 = new Date(2015, 1, 1, a1[0], a1[1]); ??`

Comment: No it doesn't, it just creates two date objects to compare the hours and minutes, and the date could be anything, as long as both dates are the same.

Answer (score 0):

check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ptfa9a04/4/)

```
function findClosestTimeInList( $listULObj, now )
{
  now = now.split( ":" ).join("");
  var arr = [];
  $listULObj.find( "li" ).each( function(){

     var value = $( this ).html().split( ":" ).join("");
     arr.push( value );
     $( this ).attr( "data-val", value );

  } );

  $listULObj.find( "li[data-val='" + closestInArray(arr, now) + "']" ).addClass( "selected" ).siblings().removeClass( "selected" );

  function closestInArray(arr, goal)
  {
    return closest = arr.reduce(function (prev, curr) {
      return (Math.abs(curr - goal) < Math.abs(prev - goal) ? curr : prev);
    });
  }
}

findClosestTimeInList( $( "ul" ), "11:18" );
```

similarly you can try for other inputs as well

```
findClosestTimeInList( $( "ul" ), "12:18" );
```

this will select 12:30 out of the list.

Answer (score 0):

**IF it's sorted and in 24 hrs format** as your comment. You may try,

```
var now = '04:01'; 
$(function(){
  var a = now.split(':');
  var date1 = new Date();
  var date2 = new Date();
  date1.setHours(a[0], a[1], 0, 0, 0);
  $("li").removeClass('selected').each(function(){
    var b = $(this).text().split(':');
    date2.setHours(b[0], b[1], 0, 0, 0);
    if (date2 >= date1) {
      $(this).addClass('selected');
      return false;
    }
  });
})
```

And **[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/nnh82rz0/1/)**